# Group wise imputations allowed?

Tags: missing-data, group-differences, data-imputation

What is the correct way of imputing missing values?
We are trying to predict the label of persons belonging to group A or B. The alternative hypothesis is that there are differences in parameters for the two groups. Should imputations be calculated based on the group an individual belongs to or should it be based on the whole sample (including both A+B)?

We can no find any literature dealing with this relevant problem. Are we missing something?

Comment: What method are you proposing to use for testing if there are differences in parameters?

Comment: We will be using some kind of prediction model, maybe logistic regression.

Comment: So you have a dataset with covariates and want to impute their group membership (group A or B). Or is it that you have a dataset, subdivided into groups A and B, and you want to predict a (sub)label for those in each group?

Comment: The last option. We have a  dataset, subdivided into groups A and B, and you want to predict a label from covariates and we need to impute some of these covariates. Do we impute them as a overall group or do we impute them based on their membership to either A or B.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the missingness in A is related to something in B? And vice versa?

Comment: no values are missing at random